# Combinatorial identity's algebraic proof without induction.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

How would you prove this combinatorial idenetity algebraically without induction?

$$\sum_{k=0}^n { x+k \choose k} = { x+n+1\choose n }$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algebraic approach. In order to do so it's convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ in a series. This way we can write e.g.
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}=[z^k](1+z)^n
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{x+k}{k}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{-x-1}{k}(-1)^k\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n[z^k](1+z)^{-x-1}(-1)^k \tag{2}\\
> &=[z^0]\frac{1}{(1+z)^{x+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(-\frac{1}{ z }\right)^k\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^0]\frac{1}{(1+z)^{x+1}}\cdot \frac{1-\left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\left(-\frac{1}{z}\right)}\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^n]\frac{z^{n+1}+(-1)^n}{(1+z)^{x+2}}\tag{5}\\
> &=(-1)^n[z^n]\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-x-2}{k}z^k\tag{6}\\
> &=(-1)^n\binom{-x-2}{n}\tag{7}\\
> &=\binom{x+n+1}{n}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use  the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (3) we do some rearrangements by using the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator  and  we also  use  the  rule
  \begin{align*}
  [z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^{q}A(z)
  \end{align*}
- In (4) apply the formula for the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*.
- In (5) we do some simplifications and use again the rule stated in comment (3).
- In (6) we  use the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)* of $\frac{1}{(1+z)^{x+2}}$. Note that we can ignore the summand $z^{n+1}$ in the numerator since it has no contribution to the coefficient of $z^n$.
- In (7) we select the coefficient of $z^n$.
- In (8) we use the rule stated in comment (1) again.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The R.H.S counts how many ways you can arrange $x+1$ $A$s and $n$ $B$s in a $x+n+1$ long sequence. As for the L.H.S, consider how many of these such sequences end in **exactly** $j$ $B$s as $j$ varies from $0$ to $n$. Hope this helps! Feel free to ask for extra clarification.

Comment: This is not an algebraic proof, but it seems to be combinatorial.

Comment: +1. A remark: it suffices to assume $x$ is a nonnegative integer, since both sides of the identitiy are polynomials in $x$, and if two polynomials agree for infinitely many values, they are the same. (So the identity holds for all $x$, not just integers.)

Comment: I think I can prove it with the the identity: ${x+n+1 \choose n} = {x+n \choose n}+ {x+n \choose n-1}$ and repeating this identity.

Comment: An alegebraic proof of this identity would be horrible - the point is that induction overcomes this problem by simplifying the calculation at each step (this becomes the inductive assumption). It is possible to battle through algebraically but it won't be nice!

Comment: Yes! Good idea - you can try to turn it into a telescoping sum. I forgot about that trick :)

Comment: Yes I forgot about this trick also, until I saw it in one excerise I am grading. :-D

Comment: I find marking work useful for that reason too! :)

Comment: @Zestylemonzi: An algebraic proof is not *that* horrible. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we seek to verify that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {q+k\choose k} = {q+n+1\choose n}.$$

The difficulty here lies in the fact that the binomial coefficients on
the LHS do not have an upper bound for the sum wired into them. We use
an Iverson bracket to get around this:

$$[[0\le k\le n]]
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{w^k}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-w} \; dw.$$

Introduce furthermore

$${q+k\choose k} = {q+k\choose q} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{q+1}} 
(1+z)^{q+k} \; dz.$$

With  the  Iverson bracket  in  place  we can  let  the  sum range  to
infinity, getting

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{q+1}} 
(1+z)^{q} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-w} 
\sum_{k\ge 0} w^k (1+z)^k
\; dw\; dz.$$

This converges when $|w(1+z)| < 1.$ Simplifying we have

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{q+1}} 
(1+z)^{q} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-w} 
\frac{1}{1-w(1+z)}
\; dw\; dz.$$

Now the residues of the inner  integral sum to zero so we can evaluate
it  by  computing  the  negative  of  the residues  at  $w=1$  and  at
$w=1/(1+z).$ We get for the first one

$$- \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{q+2}} 
(1+z)^{q} \; dz = - [z^{q+1}] (1+z)^q = 0.$$

For the second one we have

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{q+1}} 
(1+z)^{q-1} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-w} 
\frac{1}{1/(1+z)-w}
\; dw\; dz.$$

This yields

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{q+1}} 
(1+z)^{q-1} 
(1+z)^{n+1}
\frac{1}{1-1/(z+1)} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{q+2}} 
(1+z)^{q+n+1} \; dz
= {q+n+1\choose q+1}
= {q+n+1\choose n}.$$

This concludes the argument.

In order to  be rigorous we must show that  the residue at infinity
of the inner integral is zero. We get

$$\mathrm{Res}_{w=\infty}
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-w} 
\frac{1}{1-w(1+z)}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^2}
w^{n+1} \frac{1}{1-1/w} \frac{1}{1-(1+z)/w}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} 
w^{n+1} \frac{1}{w-1} \frac{1}{w-(1+z)}.$$

There  is most  certainly  no pole  here  an the  residue  is zero  as
claimed (note that $1+z$ circles the value one.)

**Addendum.** I  just realized  that it is  actually a  lot simpler
without the Iverson bracket. We get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{q+1}} 
(1+z)^{q} 
\sum_{k=0}^n (1+z)^k
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{q+1}} 
(1+z)^{q} 
\frac{(1+z)^{n+1}-1}{1+z-1}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{q+2}} 
(1+z)^{q} 
((1+z)^{n+1}-1)
\; dz.$$

This has two pieces, the second is

$$-[z^{q+1}] (1+z)^q = 0$$

and the first is

$$[z^{q+1}] (1+z)^{q+n+1} = {q+n+1\choose q+1}
= {q+n+1\choose n}.$$