# In how many solutions of equation : $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=m$

Tags: number-theory

In how many solutions of equation: $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=m$ satisfied: $x_i\in \mathbb{N}(i=\overline{1,n}),1\le x_i\le 26,n\le m\le 26n,m\in \mathbb{N}$

> This is my try:
>   Let $t_i=x_i-1\implies \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}t_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i-n=m-n$, where $0\le t_i\le 25$.
>   And I don't know how to solve it when $0\le t_i\le 25$.

Comment: Try with generating functions, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533874/how-many-possibilities/2537977#2537977).

Comment: Can you help me how to compute coefficient of $x^{m}$ in $(1+x+...+x^{26})^n$ ?

Comment: There is no easy way to do that. You can take the derivative $m$ times for example, but that is still just as hard.

Comment: I'm really grateful for all comments, I have just found it :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868044/the-number-of-n-tuples-of-nonnegative-integers-x-1-ldots-x-n-satisfying-t?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The question is asking how many integer solutions are there for $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ = m. We can use combinations with repetition. To find the number of such solutions, we can think of $m+n-1$ slots and we pick $n-1$ "dividers". The number of slots between the dividers d$_i$ and d$_{i+1}$ = x$_{i+1}$. We designate the slots before the first divider as x$_1$ and after the last divider as x$_n$. Thus every arrangements of lots and dividers is a different solution. So the number of solutions = $\binom{n+m-1}{n-1}$ = $\binom{n+m-1}{m}$.

Comment: This doesn't use OP restriction $x_i \le 26.$

Comment: it's clear that if $m \le$26, then the $x_i \le$ 26.

Comment: Joel-- yes, just noticed that, will delete comment. Meanwhile +1.