# The number of n-tuples of integers $(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ satisfying $x_1+x_2+...+x_n\equiv q(\text{ mod }m)$

Tags: number-theory

In how many solutions of equation: $x_1+x_2+...+x_n\equiv q(\text{ mod }m)$ satisfied: $x_i\in \mathbb{N}(i=\overline{1,n}),1\le x_i\le 26,0\le q\le m,q,m\in \mathbb{N}$.

> I tried solve this problem by separating it into many small problems, those are:
>   I solved: $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=q$, $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=q+m$,...
>   And I think that, it's too difficult to compute the whole solution of above problem!!
>   And I hope I can build a form for this problem!!!

Comment: It seems like $n$-$\textsf{SAT}$ problem to me! Computational complexity for this problem $O(26^n)$.

Comment: Have you made this on your own motivated by [your past problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186805/in-how-many-solutions-of-equation-x-1x-2-x-n-m) ?

Comment: Yes, @taritgoswami

Comment: In the way you approached, see that maximum value of the sum can be $26n$, so finding number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n=q,$ $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_n=q+m$ ... upto $q+tm$ which satisfies $q+tm\le 26n<q+(t+1)m$ and adding number of solutions for all cases will give the answer.

Comment: That's all I tried @taritgoswami. But i have trouble when $n\in [1;200000],m\in [100000;1000000009]$, my computer can't compute it!!

Answer (score 1):

a)

You have to look for the number of (strict) integer compositions of $n$ with no part greater than $26$, wherein $n\equiv q\ (\text{mod}\ m)$.

Let $C(n,r)$ be the number of (strict) integer compositions of $n$ with no part greater than $r$.

Its generating function is

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty C(n,r)\ x^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(x^{1}+x^{2}+...+x^{r})^{k}=\frac{1}{1-x-x^{2}-...-x^{r}}=\frac{1-x}{1-2x+x^{r+1}}.$$

For $n>0$, the numbers $C(n,r)$ are the shifted $r$-generalized Fibonacci numbers:

$$C(n,r)=F(r;n+r-1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{i}(-1)^{j}\binom{i}{j}\binom{n-j\ r-1}{i-1}^{*}$$

*) The binomial is defined to be $0$ for a negative argument.

[Hoggatt, V. E. Jr.; Lind, D. A.: Compositions and Fibonacci numbers. Fibonacci Quart. 7 (1969) (3) 253-266](https://www.fq.math.ca/7-3.html)

Without $r=0$, their OEIS sequence is [A126198](https://oeis.org/A126198).

Your numbers are among the numbers $C(n,26)$. For $n\le 26$, that are the numbers of (strict) integer compositions of $n$, $C(n)$. $\forall n>0\colon C(n)=2^{n-1}$. Their OEIS sequence is [A0117821](https://oeis.org/A011782).

b)

Collect now all $C(n,26)$ with $n\equiv q\ (\text{mod}\ m)$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^{q+k\ m}\sum_{j=0}^{i}(-1)^{j}\binom{i}{j}\binom{q+k\ m-26j-1}{i-1}^{*}$$

*) The binomial is defined to be $0$ for a negative argument.

Consider that your set $\{n\ |\ n\equiv q\ (\text{mod}\ m)\}$ is an infinite set.